# Extra nil after click button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Xcode 7 beta 6.
My single click on `save` button shows 2 times segues with `nil`s?
Where should I start troubleshooting?
[image]

```
2015-09-03 11:58:38.804 demoProject[27331:856955] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1336863583_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
sending profileNew object to TableViewController
2015-09-03 11:58:46.238 demoProject[27331:856955] I'm back from other controller!
nil
Save btn clicked addUIViewController
Name : Optional("txt")
Age : Optional("22")
Specialty : Optional("you")
Description : Desciptionddd
sending profileNew object to TableViewController
2015-09-03 11:58:46.240 demoProject[27331:856955] I'm back from other controller!
nil
```

I have 2 ViewController. First is `ProfileTableViewController`. Second is `addUIViewController` .
Application flow is 
1. Tab plus sign on the `Select` scene.
2. Add Name, Age, Specialty, Description. Then Save.
3. Unwind segue sends back new profile object.
4. TableViewController update the record in the scene.
Right now I am confusing. Is my implementation of unwind segue is wrong?

**Profile.swift**

```
import UIKit
class Profile {
    var name : String;
    var age : Int;
    var specialty : String?;
    var description : String?;
    init?(name : String, age: Int, specialty : String?, description : String?){
        self.name = name;
        self.age = age;
        self.specialty = specialty;
        self.description = description;
        if (name.isEmpty || age < 0){
            return nil;
        }
    };
}
```

**ProfileTableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var profiles = [Profile]();

    var profileNew : Profile?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        func loadSampleProfiles(){
            let profile1 = Profile(name: "Ant", age: 18, specialty: "Runner", description: "Ants are eusocial insects of the family Formicidae /fɔrˈmɪsɨdiː/ and, along with the related wasps and bees EOF");
            let profile2 = Profile(name: "Bee", age: 11, specialty: "Sky Diver", description: "Bees are flying insects closely related to wasps and ants, known for their role in pollination EOF");
            let profile3 = Profile(name: "Cat", age: 14, specialty: "Stalker", description: "The domestic cat[1][2] (Felis catus EOF");
            let profile4 = Profile(name: "Dog", age: 19, specialty: "Proxy", description: "In engineering a dog is a tool that prevents movement or imparts movement by offering physical obstructioEOF");
            let profile5 = Profile(name: "Earth", age: 20, specialty: "Supplier", description: "Earth, also called the world[n 5] (and, less frequently, Gaia[n 6] or, in Latin, Terra[26]), is the thirEOF");
            profiles += [profile1!, profile2!, profile3!, profile4!, profile5!];
        };
        loadSampleProfiles();

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return profiles.count;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "ProfileTableViewCell";
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell
        let profile = profiles[indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text = profile.name;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true);
        let row = indexPath.row;
        print("Row:\(row)");
        print(profiles[row].name , profiles[row].age);
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segueTest", sender: row);
    }

    // Mark: Actions
    @IBAction func backFromOtherController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        NSLog("I'm back from other controller!")
        print(profileNew?.toString());

        //add the new profile
        if(profileNew != nil){
            profiles += [profileNew!];

            //update the tableview
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: profiles.count, inSection: 0);
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            print(indexPath);
        }

    }

}
```

**addUIController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class addUIViewController: UIViewController {

    // Mark: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var addNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addAgeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addSpecialtyTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descUIViewController: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    }

    // Mark: Actions

    var profileNew : Profile?;
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func saveHit(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Save btn clicked addUIViewController");
        print("Name : " + addNameTextField.text);
        print("Age : " + addAgeTextField.text);
        print("Specialty : " + addSpecialtyTextField.text);
        print("Description : " + descUIViewController.text);
        if(addNameTextField.text == nil || addAgeTextField.text == nil || addSpecialtyTextField.text == nil || descUIViewController.text == nil){
            self.profileNew = nil;
            print("Got nil");
        }

        let profileNew = Profile(name : addNameTextField.text!, age : Int(addAgeTextField.text!)!, specialty : addSpecialtyTextField.text!, description : descUIViewController.text! );
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("profileNew", sender: profileNew)
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "profileNew"){
            let viewControllerReceiver = segue.destinationViewController as? ProfileTableViewController;
            print("sending profileNew object to TableViewController");
            viewControllerReceiver?.profileNew = profileNew;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: do you know where that "`nil`" is coming from?  if not, you can add a little bit of extra information to your calls to "`print`".  For example:  "`print("addNameTextField is \(addNameTextField.text)")`".  That way you can easily isolate which "`print`" is printing a nil.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Name -> Optional("txt"), Age -> Optional("22"), Specialty -> Optional("you"), Description -> Desciptionddd. I will put my `print` line more informative.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause** : ctrl drag `save` button to `Exit`.
**Solution** : Delete and Re-created segue by drag from `Title` to `Exit`.